# библиотеки для ковертирования MDI в PDF

Tags: c#, node.js, office

Подскажите, есть ли хоть какая-нибудь библиотека по конвертированию/извлечению из изображений из устаревшего формата microsoft document image format в pdf? Желательно на C# или node.js?